# Org-mode tag search results in separate buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, when I do a search on tags with C-c \, I just get the current buffer highlighted in yellow for matching tags.
I would like to get a sparse tree in a separate buffer.
I have read that this depends on variable org-agenda-window-setup, but I don't have this variable,when I check with alt-x
I am using emacs24 on ubuntu.
How can I get the sparse tree in a separate buffer?
Thanks

saikari

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer.  I don't use sparse trees because I prefer custom agenda views.  You may wish to consider using the built-in `org-tags-view` instead of a sparse tree, which by default creates a separate window containing the results.